# $p$-group acting on a finite set

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, p-groups

Let $G$ be a $p$-group. Prove that if $G$ acts on a finite set $X$ and $p$ does not divide $|X|$, then $X$ contains some element that is fixed by every element in $G$.

Any thoughts? I'm stumped because $G$ is not necessarily finite.

Answer (score 2):

For each $x\in X$, the orbit of $x$ is the set $\mathcal O(x)=\{gx:g\in G\}$. Since $G$ is a $p$-group, $|\mathcal O(x)|$ is a power of $p$. Note that it can not be infinite because $X$ is finite.

Note that the set orbits is a partition in $X$. Since the cardinal of each orbit is a power of $p$, $|X|$ must be also a multiple of $p$, unless some of these orbits have cardinal $p^0=1$.

Comment: How do you know that the orbit must have an order of power p (I ask since the orbit consists of elements from X, not from G)?

Comment: If $K$ is the kernel of the action, then $G/K$ is a finite $p$-group. So $G$ being infinite is not really a problem. The size of the orbit of $x$ is the index $|G:G_x|$, where $G_x$ is the stabilizer of $x$. Since $K \le G_x$, this must be a power of $p$.

Comment: But the kernel doesn't have to be finite, which would imply that G/K does not have to be finite.